# PHP debugging in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-debugger, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to configure Indigo so I can debug PHP in eclipse. I have looked at a ton of different tutorials and blogs online that try to explain it but none work so far. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I use a generic LAMP stack with PHP 5.3.3 executables configured in eclipse.

Does anyone have a good guide for installing Zend or XDebug in Eclipse Indigo?

Comment: Did you have a working configuration in Helios or any other earlier version of eclipse?

Comment: @travega no I have never tried to debug PHP before. I am aware that eclipse no longer natively supports PDT. Does this mean that it cannot be done in Indigo? Will I have to go back to Helios just to debug PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is something I posted a while back which took a while to figure out. I got it working in Helios but it has worked for me in Indigo also: [Can I link the Zend PDT (eclipse) to a browser action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092838/can-i-link-the-zend-pdt-eclipse-to-a-browser-action)

Comment: thanks for the link. I am unsure about what you mean by  http://[local URL path to your project]? Im not debugging on a server and my development source project is not in the apache web root so how can I provide a url here?

Comment: What I have set up in my environment is an apache site config for a url like: user.website.com and I add this as an alias for my localhost and global IP in my hosts config. If you haven't done this before I can point you in the right direction?